# DataGrid Creation and DateFormat

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq-to-sql

[image]

My datagrid has ETA_DATE, but the format should be dd.mm.yyyy. How can I change the format? My C# SilverLight code is:

```
DataGrid dataGridShips = new DataGrid();
dataGridShips.Margin = new Thickness(5, 77, 5, 5);
dataGridShips.Width = 590;
dataGridShips.ItemsSource = e.Result;
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are you autogenerating the columns or are they defined in xaml?

Comment: They are beeing autogenerated.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`, add columns manually.
see: [Defining Columns for a Silverlight DataGrid](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scmorris/archive/2008/03/27/defining-columns-for-a-silverlight-datagrid.aspx)

Step 2. Write your own datetime converter
see: [Formate value using convertors](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/How-to-format-a-binding-value-using-convertors.aspx)

Or with AutoGenerateColumns set to True, you could go option 2:
[Customize Auto-Generated Columns in the DataGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

You may try set display format on your properties

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "format")]
```

But it does not work from my experience.

Comment: I dont understand. I alreaddy have a datalist. But I need to create the colums first? How can I do this in C#?